# What ist the correct way to create a new layer without geometry using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, layers

Using PyQGIS, a new vector layer can be created and added to the project like this:

```
newlayer = QgsVectorLayer('Point', 'points_layer', 'memory')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(newlayer)
```

What is the correct way to add a new temporary scratch layer that does not contain geometry using PyQGIS? It works like this:

```
newlayer2 = QgsVectorLayer('None', 'table_layer', 'memory')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(newlayer2)
```

However, it feels strange to use `QgsVectorLayer()` here, as the result is not a vector layer. Is there a more generic alternative to `QgsVectorLayer()` or is a layer without geometry treated as a vector layer per default in QGIS?

Comment: Why it feels strange? It is a vector Layer. Yes it is empty, but a vector layer. What do you want to do with the empty layer?

Comment: You are right, it's not a real problem that I addressed here - everything works fine with the code. And maybe you just answered the more general question behind it: A layer without geometry that only contains attribute data is being treated like a vector layer in QGIS and there is no need to have another QGIS/PyQGIS layer type like e.g. "QgsTableLayer". Correct?